# Read JungUm Global (Samsung) file

Tags: file, format

I need to read plain text from  JungUm Global (another named as "samsung") document (.GUL extension) but didn't found any spec on this format.

Please advice any resource / solution to achieve this!

Here a sample [document](http://www.sendspace.com/file/fsgxkb) (it contains only one "hello" word).

Thank you!

Comment: Can you please upload the sample document again? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I only have found this:
http://www.jungum.com/ReNew/En/Customer/Qna_View.html?product_id=00&qType=&pageNo=1&id=12

"We are allowed to provid "*.TLB" files and API examples only for who has Jungum Global License."
"In order to provide you with 'JungUmGW.tlb' file, you need to have JungUm Global License."

It links to
http://www.jungum.com/html/en/04_Customer/04_02_Customer_tip_list.html?part=Customer&sec=2&Pmode=v&id=1&temp1=0
but that is now dead.

Unfortunately these links just talk about some SDK/TLB-file which you have to get from them.

Comment: You should have put some information into the answer itself instead of linking to information which will disappear in the future (and has in fact already disappeared by now.)

Comment: Thanks for the downvote, the sample document was also not uploaded again